# passing angular services through modules

Tags: angularjs, angular-module

I am looking at the code of [HotTowel-Angular](https://github.com/johnpapa/HotTowel-Angular) and I am trying to make a small example using it but I can't get it to work.

This is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['common']);

var common = angular.module('common', []);

common.factory('commonf', ['$rootScope', '$timeout', commonFactory]);



function commonFactory($rootScope, $timeout){

    var service = {
    $rootScope: $rootScope,
    $timeout: $timeout
    }

    return service;

}

app.controller('TestCtrl', ['commonf', testctrl]);

function testctrl(commonf) {

   activate(); 

   var $timeout = commonf.$timeout;

   function activate() {

     $timeout(function () {
     alert("test");
     }, 5);

   }

}
```

The idea is to keep all common angular services that are used throughout the app inside a service which is injected to all services/controllers.

When I try to do this above I get the following error:

> "$timeout is not a function";

Edit: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/52wFiG82K5RGjTEhV1OK)

Comment: You inject your service as `commonf`, but you assign `common.$timeout`. Are those typos in your question or is this actually in your code? And please fix the indentation, your code is horrible to read.

Comment: That was a typo sorry, fixed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling activate() before you pulled the dependency from commonf. Change to this:

```
function testctrl(commonf) {
  // define this first so that $timeout is defined when activate is executed
  var $timeout = commonf.$timeout;

  activate(); 

  function activate() {
    $timeout(function () {
      alert("test");
    }, 5);
}
```

In javascript, it is generally good practice to have variable declaration as the first statement in your function.

Comment: Doh! Didn't see that. Thanks :)